# Polymer, IE11 dom-repeat no rendering option tags

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, custom-element, polymer-3.x

I'm having issues specifically with IE11. This code works fine in Chrome/Firefox/Edge. I don't see what I am doing that would cause this to not work.

Here is the part of my polymer element's shadow dom that is breaking:

```
  <template is="dom-if" if="[[showSelect]]]">
    <select value="{{selectValue::change}}">
      <option value="0" selected$="{{matchesDefault(0)}}">All</option>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{excludeNumbers}}" as="number">
        <option value="[[number]]" selected$="[[isExclude(number)]]">Skip [[number]]s</option>
      </template>
    </select>
  </template>
```

What I'm attempting to do and is working in Chrome/FF/Edge but not IE11:

- If  is set, show the shadow dom `<select>`.
- Bind this.selectValue to update when the dropdown is changed.
- Loop through `this.excludeNumbers` and write them as `<option>` nested inside of the `<select>`, selecting them if they are

What I've tested so far:

- Removing all attributes from the `<option>` tags

  - Result: No change,  still do not render
- Removing the default `<option value="0" selected$="{{matchesDefault(0)}}">All</option>` from the markup

  - Result: No change,  still do not render
- Moving the `<template is="dom-repeat">` markup outside of the `<select>`, just under the opening `<template>` tag that checks is `[[showSelect]]` is set & changing them from `<option>` to `<span>` tags.

  - Result: Successfully writes span tags
- Running `polymer build` and testing IE10 on the built code

  - Result: No change

Does anyone see what I have wrong? Any ideas on what I can test?

Any ideas are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue, `tables` and `selects` do not work with `dome-repeat` in IE11
There is an issue for this opened in [Github here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1735) with no working solution

One solution is to use a custom element, maybe something like [paper-dropdown-menu](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-dropdown-menu)

Comment: Thank you for the information! I spent way too much time on that yesterday (hah).